# How do I loop through the elements of an object and return its value in TypeScript&React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following enum and state:

```
enum FilterId {
    filter1,
    filter2,
    filter3,
    filter4,
    filter5,
}
```

```
type FiltersInComponent = { [key in FilterId]: boolean };

const [appliedFilters, setAppliedFilters] = React.useState<FiltersInComponent>()
```

Question 1: How do I initialise the `appliedFilters` state to (in short notation):

```
{ 
  filter1: false, 
  filter2: false, 
  filter3: false, 
  filter4: false, 
  filter5: false 
}
```

Question 2: How do I loop through `appliedFilters` and display a checkbox?
I have the following so far:

```
{Object.keys(appliedFilters)
    .filter((v) => !isNaN(Number(v)))
    .map((option) => {
        const isChecked: boolean = appliedFilters[option];
        return (
            <>
                <Checkbox checked={isChecked} />
                <Typography>
                    {optionMessage(Number(option))}
                </Typography>
            </>
        );
     })}
```

But I'm getting the following error for `appliedFilters[option]`

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FiltersInComponent'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'FiltersInComponent'.
```

Comment: did the answer help or do you require further info

Comment: it's kind ofgood courtesy to mark an answer as valid if someone takes the time to help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you've defined this enum.

You're looking for something more along these lines:

```
type FilterId = 'filter1' | 'filter2' | 'filter3' | 'filter4' | 'filter5'

const foo = () => {
  type FiltersInComponent = { [key in FilterId]: boolean }

  const [appliedFilters, setAppliedFilters] =
    React.useState<FiltersInComponent>({
      filter1: false,
      filter2: false,
      filter3: false,
      filter4: false,
      filter5: false,
    })
```

As you have it right now `[key in FilterId]` evaluates to

```
type FiltersInComponent = {
    0: boolean;
    1: boolean;
    2: boolean;
    3: boolean;
    4: boolean;
}
```

as your enum values are the defaults of 0,1,2 etc. You could if you wanted, add enum values of 'filter1' etc  and then use a string template literal to extract `type FilterIdType = ${FilterId}`; But if you're going to modify your enum and have control over it you're better off just going for the simpler union type.

Comment: how would you do the `onChange` for the checkboxes and update the state?

Comment: that sounds like a separate question right?